# Is there any better way to implement TagView for Android recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have discovered integrating TagView is pretty much difficult
I have googled and could finally find below article
https://medium.com/@amindevv/create-a-taglayout-using-recyclerview-and-custom-adapter-on-android-bb73b803089d

But it doesn't look good because we could not refresh items.
We should set recyclerview adapter again and again each time we need change items
Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is Material Chip component fit to your requirement?

https://material.io/components/chips#types